# find a real-valued convex function defined on compact set where it does not have global maxima

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose f(x) is a real-valued convex function defined on a compact convex set 
 in the Euclidean space.

Now I want to find f(x) such that a global maxima does not exist.

I think if I can find a function f on a compact set of R^1 with no local maxima, than I can make such a function g on R^2 by letting g(theta,r)=f(theta)I{r=1}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in one dimension: assume that $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex. Then,
the graph of $f$ lies below the line connecting $(0,f(0))$ and $(1,f(1))$. Hence, $0$ or $1$ is a global maximizer.

In more than one dimension, one can, however, construct counterexamples. Let $B_1(0)$ be the closed unit ball in a Hilbert space, e.g., in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then define $f : B_1(0) \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$f(x) = 0 \quad \text{if } \|x\| < 1$$
and set $f(x)$ to some arbitrary, nonnegative value for any $\|x\| = 1$. Then, if you choose this correctly, $f$ will not attain its supremum on $B_1(0)$.

Comment: That is what my question is. Since on ||x||=1, you have to construct a function w.r.t  angle with no maxima. But I tried realization of Brownian motion and Weierstrass function but both of them have maxima

Comment: You should realize, that you have *none* constraints on $f(x)$ for $\|x\| = 1$ beside non-negativity. So you do not need continuity and could just take some $f(x)$, which is unbounded. E.g. $f(x) = 1/\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle of $x$, and some arbitrary value if $\theta = 0$.

Comment: K. I totally agree. Thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

A convex function either has a singleton domain or its domain has a non-empty (relative) interior. Since we are in a Euclidean space that convex function would be continuous so by the Weierstrass Theorem would attain both global extrema.

Comment: Note that the convex function is only continuous in the interior of its domain. Hence, if it is defined on $[0,1]$, it is continuous in $(0,1)$, but not in the endpoints. Since $(0,1)$ is not compact, you cannot apply Weierstraß' theorem.

Comment: @gerw By real-valued function I understood that it has the whole space as a domain. You are right with your interpretation.

Comment: But the question is about a function, which is "defined on a compact convex set".